# Completeness of $(\mathcal M (2,\mathbb R),\lVert \cdot\rVert)$

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, banach-spaces

- Let $\mathcal M (2,\mathbb R)$ be the space of $2\times2$ matrices with inner product $ \langle A,B\rangle=\operatorname{tr}(AB^T)  $
  We define the normed space : $  \bbox[1px,border:1px solid green] { X:=(\mathcal M (2,\mathbb R),\lVert \cdot\rVert)}$ with **norm** $\bbox[1px,border:1px solid green] {\lVert A\rVert=\sqrt{\langle A,A\rangle } }$
- I want to check the **completeness** (a.k.a *Banach*) of $X$ but how can we define the limit of a sequence in that space?
  I.e Let $A_n$ be a sequence of matrices  s.t $A_n=\bigg ($$ \left[
  \begin{array}{cc}
    x_1&y_1\\
    z_1&w_1
  \end{array}
  \right] $$, $$ \left[
  \begin{array}{cc}
    x_2&y_2\\
    z_2&w_2
  \end{array}
  \right] $$,...., $$ \left[
  \begin{array}{cc}
    x_n&y_n\\
    z_n&w_n
  \end{array}
  \right] ,....$$\bigg)         $.
  Is my question misleading? let me know.

Comment: Hint: in the product topology of normed vector spaces a sequence converges if and only if each canonical projection of the sequence converge. Now note that the space that you have is isometric to an Euclidean space with the $\|\cdot\|_2$ norm, and that this norm is equivalent to the product norm.

Comment: Very interesting, thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The distance is given by the norm. So $A_n\to A$ means $\|A_n-A\|\to0$. Here the norm, if you make the computation, is
$$\tag1
\|A\|=\biggl({\sum_{k,j}a_{kj}^2}\biggr)^{1/2}.
$$
From $(1)$ it is easy to see that
$$
|a_{kj}|\leq\|A\|
$$
for any $k,j=1,2$. So, if $\{A_n\}$ is Cauchy, then for any $k,j$ you have that $$|(A_n)_{k,j}-(A_m)_{k,j}|\leq \|A_n-A_m\|.$$ Thus the sequence of $k,j$ entries is Cauchy. Now you can use the completeness of $\mathbb R$ to obtain the limit for each $k,j$, and you need to show that entrywise convergence implies norm-convergence; this last property follows easily from
$$\tag2
\|A\|\leq\max\{|a_{k,j}|:\ k,j=1,2\}. 
$$